# CREATE command denied to user - Access Migration -> MySQL (SQL Workbench)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, microsoft-access

Doing a MS Access to MySQL Migration with SQL Workbench. At the create Schema point I am getting the following error for all tables (9):

```
WARNING: Error executing 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `HWAMembers`.`2016 Memberships` (
  `ID` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `Donation` DECIMAL(19,4) NULL,
  `Crest` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `MemberID` INT(10) NULL,
  `Type` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  INDEX `Membership ID` (`MemberID` ASC),
  INDEX `MembershipID` (`ID` ASC))'
CREATE command denied to user
```

MySQL is hosted by GoDaddy. I have ensured that the user has all privileges and ensured my IP was added to the Hosts. I am completely new to SQL. The need for the migration was we had build our database in Access, we have a need for mySQL as were creating a front end to the database.

I do appreciate everyone's time on this but I ask that those consider my limited backend knowledge.

If this was asked before I apologize in advance, I have searched for the question for some time but couldn't quite find those with the exact issue or with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve this. It appears that with this migration method that you must have a Database with the same file name as the MS Access file.